# Скрыть блок div методом PHP через 5 секунд

Tags: php, javascript

Суть кода в том, чтобы полностью убрать фрейм из исходного кода страницы сайта через 5 секунд. 
И как показать фрейм только при первой сессии? Если пользователь обновит страницу, он не должен видеть этот фрейм еще раз.

```
<?php

if (!$user)
{
echo '<iframe id="player" width="425" height="350" src="http://" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
}
else 
{
eche "Привет! $user !";
}
```

Comment: @maxoraa, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('player').outerHTML = "Привет! <?=$user?> !";}, 5000);
</script>

<iframe id="player" width="425" height="350" src="http://" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень хорошо, но ваш код визуально спрятал фрейм - это плохо. А я бы хотел, чтоб вместо фрейма было (Привет! $user !) 

Сейчас там в исходном коде это:

    <iframe id="player" javascript=""  width="425" height="350" src="http://ivandan.com/" frameborder="0">123</iframe> 

А должно быть это с задержкой в 5 секунд:

    Привет! $user !

Comment: @maxoraa я обновил код, теперь он полностью удаляет фрейм. Нужно, чтобы просто удалял или чтобы после удаления сразу показывал "Привет! $user!"?

Comment: Это намного лучше, заранее спасибо большое. ))) Но в данном примере код пропадает только при обновлении страницы. Но при первом переходе он не пропадает полностью, только если обновить страницу, а чтоб пропал при первом переходе, можно сделать?

Comment: @maxoraa после 5 секунд у меня он пропадает полностью. Вам нужно, чтобы при уничтожении фрейма сразу же показывалась строка из условия лжи "Привет! $user!"? То есть чтобы он стал на место фрейма?

Comment: @maxoraa теперь в коде всё точно так, как вам было нужно